# How to typehint nonstandard containers (e.g. OrderedDict) in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, restructuredtext, type-hinting

I am using PyCharm as an IDE for the development of a Python 2.7 program. Since there are no annotations before Python 3, I use restructuredText for docstrings so that PyCharm can infer the types of parameters and member variables.

This works fine for standard and unparametrized types, but I cannot use get it to work e.g. with `collections.OrderedDict`. For example I have an `OrderedDict` with keys of type `str` and values of type `MyDataSet`.

I can think of the following representations in the docstring

```
# Values are recognized as correct class, but _member class is imprecise
:type _member: dict[str, MyDataSet]

# Class of _member is determined correctly, but values types are unknown
:type _member: OrderedDict
:type _member: OrderedDict[str, MyDataSet]

# Class of _member is imprecise and values types are unknown
:type _member: OrderedDict | dict[str, MyDataSet]
:type _member: dict[str, MyDataSet] | OrderedDict[str, MyDataSet]
```

For now I use the first method because knowledge of the value class Is important for refactoring. Is there a way to specify the content (key/value) types for custom containers such as `OrderedDict`?

Comment: What is the problem? It seems that you suggestions are correct. See sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5.1/domains.html and search for "Container types such as lists and dictionaries".

Comment: @Humbalan PyCharm seems to parse the key value types only for the builtin containers(`dict`, `list` and `tuple`). For other types (such as `OrderedDict`) this information is lost. Which means I do not get type hinting and incorrect matches appear in "find usage" and refactoring dialogs.